# Unique identifier for every interface-implementation

Tags: java, interface

I have a package-private interface called `AbstractServer` which offers three methods: `start()`, `stop()` and `init()`.

For every new server, I implement the interface and override those methods. After that, I register this new server to my public `ServerManager`-class, which collects all servers in a `HashMap` and calls their exposed methods in a certain order.

So, starting all registered servers from somewhere else in the code simply looks like this:

```
ServerManager.INSTANCE.startServers();
```

The problem I'm currently facing is, that I want to be able to remove a Server from the `ServerManager`s map.

My idea was to introduce a `public static final String IDENTIFIER`-field to the interface and use it as the keys in the `HashMap`. This way, to remove a Server from the `ServerManager`, I would write:

```
ServerManager.INSTANCE.removeServer(HttpServer.IDENTIFIER);
```

The problem is, that I can't have an "abstract" attribute in the interface and therefore can't force the implementations to override it.

I can also not use a normal method (non-static) because the constructor of the Server-implementations will be package-private.

As an alternative, I thought about using the `Class` of the implementations as the keys in the `HashMap` so I can write something like this:

```
ServerManager.INSTANCE.removeServer(HttpServer.class);
```

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Using the class as a key is a good choice.

Comment: What are you using currently as the key in your Map and can there be multiple instances of a specific server?

Comment: @quaylar I'm using a String, but it is not stored anywhere, so you must know the exact value. Feels like bat practice to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know there's ever going to be at most one instance per implementing class, then using the `Class` object as the key is a pretty natural solution.

If you don't, then clearly the IDs would have to be instance-specific and not class-specific.

Comment: There will only be on instance of every implementation.

Answer (score 0):

What about defining an enum `ServerIdentifier` for all possible Server-Types and in the interface:

```
ServerIdentifier getServerIdentifier();
```

Your map could then be a `Map<ServerIdentifier, List<AbstractServer>>` and you would even be able to manage multiple instances of one Server-Type...

Advantage over using the Class-Object as a key would just be a more natural way of dealing with the server types, since you can use an enum and dont have to compare Class-Objects...

Comment: The problem is, that I need to get the identifier (what ever it might be) in a static way since the constructor is package-private. The `.class`-member is always available this way, whereas you can't define static methods in interfaces.